# Google Maps v3 zoom_changed issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with two different types of markers. I want to show the type 1 if the map has a zoom level <= to a defined number, and the type 2 otherwise.
I had this implementation with the api 2, but now i can't reproduce it using api 3.
I used the zoomend function and it worked like a charm, while in v3 it seems that there are some issues with the zoom_changed event, is it possible?

Comment: So what is the exact problem with the zoom_changed() event?

Answer (score 3):

I have had problems moving from V2 -> V3 with zoom_changed so I'll take a guess that you had a similar problem. I found that I needed to wait for the bounds_changed event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, "zoom_changed", function () {
    var eventListener = google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, "bounds_changed", function () {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(eventListener);
        // Perform actions previously done on zoomend
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to sort this?

I'd use something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();

    if (currentZoom >= 3) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```